# Authentication Failed: 403 Forbidden Error while Connecting Wordpress to Zapier

Tags: wordpress, zapier

I hope you're all doing well. I am currently facing an issue while trying to connect my WordPress site to Zapier, and I was hoping someone here could lend a hand.

When attempting to establish the connection, I encountered the following error message: "Authentication Failed: 403 Forbidden: Access Denied." I found the error to be quite perplexing, as I followed the usual steps and made sure to deactivate several plugins that could potentially interfere with the connection. Additionally, I explored various solutions mentioned in past forum posts, but none seemed to resolve the issue.

I also consulted the resources provided by Zapier (https://zapier.com/help/doc/common-problems-wordpress#403-forbidden-error) to address the 403 Forbidden error, but to no avail.

At this point, I'm feeling a bit stuck and frustrated. Therefore, I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or experiences that any of you might have encountered in resolving similar issues. Please feel free to share any potential solutions or workarounds that I might not have considered yet.

Thank you all in advance for your time and assistance. I look forward to hearing your thoughts.

I have already reached out to both my hosting provider, Hostinger, and Zapier support for assistance. Unfortunately, neither of them were able to provide a definitive solution. I have tried multiple troubleshooting steps, including deactivating plugins and implementing suggestions from past forum posts, but the error persists.